# update global variables inside while loop

Tags: php

Can someone please explain the most efficient method to return a value from within a while loop, for use before the while loop initiated.
Tried the following-

```
echo $var1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
    $var1 = $row[0];
}
```

Returns unset variable.

I also tried:

```
$var1= 1;
echo $var1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
    global $var1;    
    $var1 = $row[0];
}
```

Just echos 1.

Comment: Is your `while` loop actually executing...?

Comment: yep. can get the value from below/after the while loop. Just not before.

Comment: You are trying to eat your omelette before you break the eggs. You can't print your variables before you set them. Making the variable `global` does not magically reverse time.

Comment: Check your mysql query. any result? And what is `$query1`?

Comment: PHP is an *imperative* language, meaning *stuff executes in the order you write it*...

Comment: ok got it. it makes logical sense now. otherwise the variable could be set in two places and if it didn't follow the order of the page, it wouldn't know what to be. a confused variable. Thanks for the wake up.!

Comment: Why vote to close? To be sure, it's a very basic question, but it's a valid one. This is not nearly the first time I saw this mistake being made by learners. Please keep it open.

Comment: @jason3w: It seems 2unco's answer helped you. Please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound strange, but is your echo before or after the while loop? In your above example, you show it to us as being before the loop - and we wouldn't expect that to show much.

Comment: yeah before. but isn't that what global is for? I'm guessing not. Kind of doesn't work when i think of it logically.

Comment: You can access the variable before the loop because it is global, sure. But the fact is that until the loop happens, that variable isn't being set to anything (well, it's being set explicitly to 1 in the second example). You want to wait until after the loop performs and changes the variable before echoing it. So when you're echoing the first one, it's finding the global variable (assuming it was defined before the echo), but since it's null valued nothing is coming out.

Comment: @jason3w: `global` means you can access it from somewhere outside the current function. It's like having a delivery option on your restaurant - you can eat at home, you don't have to come to them to eat their omelette. Still won't give you omelette before it's cooked.

Comment: @Amadan thanks Amadan. I'm actually vegan, but i can translate that to a vegan analogy using php! ;) The analogy stands though. Perfect logic. Can't argue with that.